# Web app fails to download files on certain browsers

Tags: jsf, download, zip, response

I have a very strange problem with file downloads on my application. I searched long and wide and haven't been able to find a suitable solution. I will try to describe the problem as clearly as possible in the hope that someone out there can help.

I have a JSF application in which after submitting a form, the user downloads a dynamically generated report consisting of a zip file containing one xls and one csv file. The size of the zip file and the time to generate the report depend on the time period the user selects.

On the server, I treat the response like this:

```
response.reset();
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"file.zip\"");
```

Then I generate the csv and xls files on a temp directory (unique per session) on the server and zip'em up directly to the response output stream.

When selecting short time periods for the search criteria, all is fine. But when increasing the time interval, IE and Firefox seem to "lose" the response. On IE the request remains 'Pending', while FF shows the 'Connecting' spinner on the tab, even when the server has finished writing the file to the response. There are no exceptions in the server log in any case. The download dialog never shows up.

What puzzles me is that Chromium opens the file sucessfully every time without problems regardless of search criteria. Also the problem seems to come from the Test deployment, because I have been unable to reproduce the issue in my local environment by setting breakpoints and waiting a couple of minutes, etc.

The wait times and file sizes are not something out of this world, I'm talking about less than 1MB and less than 2 minutes to complete the report.

Here's the relevant request and response headers of a successful report using FF (removed host, real file name, etc):

```
Request:
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0
Connection:keep-alive
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Response:
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Server:Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=98
Expires:Mon, 08 Apr 2013 11:43:49 GMT
Date:Mon, 08 Apr 2013 11:43:48 GMT
Content-Type:application/zip;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="file.zip"
Connection:Keep-Alive
Cache-Control:max-age=1
```

It seems safe to assume that the response is indeed getting to the browser, but somehow gets messed up and neither IE nor FF show the download dialog.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention that I've tried debugging the request/response cycle with every tool available: built in dev tools on IE, FF, Firebug, Fiddler... unfortunaltely not very useful with the affected browsers since response doesn't show up in the first place.

**Edit 2:** Assorted shots in the dark:

- Chrome inspector shows this message in the console after requesting the report: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "https://xxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxx.faces".
- Chrome inspector shows the request as "canceled" in the Network tab, though it saves the file correctly
- On the rest of pages, the response encoding is UTF-8, however for the zip file is ISO-8859-1. This seems to be a default value, as far as I know it's not being specified anywhere. I got it to display "application/zip;charset=UTF-8" but would need to deploy to the Test server in order to see if this has any effect.

**Edit 3:** Update: Bypassing Apache on the Test deployment, and letting Tomcat handle everything (like in the local environment) makes the problem go away, making Apache the main culprit. The only apparent differences are the keep-alive response headers which are put there by Apache. 
I've been playing around with Tomcat on the local environment trying to find a configuration that is causing the issue, but no luck so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried adding an appropriate `Content-Length` header?

Comment: Hi @CBroe, I am zipping the dynamically generated files directly to the response's output stream. As far as I know, it is not possible to know the file size in this situation. I would have to save the zip file on disk, calculate the file size, then stream the file from disk...

Comment: Giving up. See my answer on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/497901/strange-apache-timeout-on-certain-browsers/498472#498472